# Как в Canvas удалить определённый объект?

Tags: python, canvas

Подскажите пожалуйста. Я сделал игру лабиринт и её суть в том, чтобы человечек(квадратик) двигался по лабиринту и собирал ключики(квадратики) от двери(два квадратика),и надо, всего лишь одну команду, чтобы при касании игрока и ключика ключик исчезал

Часть кода:

```
for k in keys:
    if player in c.find_overlapping(k[0], k[1], k[2], k[3]):
        key_num += 1
```

После этого должна быть строка с удалением объекта, переменной k

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Сейчас добавил, вот так? Прошу вас, если у вас есть ответ очень интересно его узнать

Comment: это ткинтер ? canvas  разные бывают

Comment: Да, ткинтер это

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в Canvas удалить объект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132039/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-canvas-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82)