# Как в Canvas удалить объект?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

Подскажите пожалуйста. Я сделал игру лабиринт и её суть в том, чтобы человечек(квадратик) двигался по лабиринту и собирал ключики(квадратики) от двери(два квадратика),и надо, всего лишь одну команду, чтобы при касании игрока и ключика ключик исчезал

Часть кода:

```
for k in keys:
    if player in c.find_overlapping(k[0], k[1], k[2], k[3]):
        key_num += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
название_обьекта.destroy()
```

Это уничтожает объект

Comment: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'destroy' - ошибка, после ввода этого

Comment: canvas.delete(название)  тоже не поможет ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно знать id удаляемого объекта, по нему удалять. Пример:

```
rectangle_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)

# ...

canvas.delete(rectangle_id)
```

Также можно присвоить нескольким объекта тег (текстовому имени группы объектов), по этому тегу удалить все объекты:

```
canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, tag='key1')
canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, tag='key1')
canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, tag='key1')

# ...

canvas.delete('key1')
```